# Using knit_child in RStudio to manage thesis .Rnw chapters in master .Rnw. \ref and \label don't work now

Tags: latex, rstudio, knitr

To say that I am a LaTeX amateur is an understatement, though by some miracle, I am managing to write my thesis in it. I am using RStudio to write and compile my thesis, due to all of my analysis being done in R and wanting the ability to insert dynamic plots etc.

As my thesis has increased in size, I wanted to break the chapters off into sub .Rnw files so that I could work on each chapter independently (with my need for R code within each chapter ruling out using .tex files). The only way I could get this to work, was using \Sexpr{knit_child('chapter.Rnw')}. I weave my files using knitr rather than Sweave as again, that is the only I can get it to compile correctly. Unfortunately, I've never managed to understand why!

Nevertheless, this is working very nicely, is much easier to manage and my plots and R code are compiling correctly, but my previously functioning \ref and \label commands no longer work. Well, they work within a chapter, but not between them.

I include my main document here and the latex commands that I think are relevant to my question. I have googled this all morning, but am getting nowhere alone.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %What kind of document 
\usepackage{titlesec} %can actually name chapters rather than having "Chapter 1" etc
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{library}

% ----------- KNITR SETUP ------------------------
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(fig.path='figures/plots-', fig.align='center', fig.show='hold', eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE)
options(replace.assign=TRUE,width=80)
# setwd("C:/Users/cainswor/Box Sync/Imperial/Reports/Thesis")
setwd("D:/BoxSync/BoxSync/Reports/Thesis")
data_loc <- "D:/BoxSync/BoxSync/Reports/Thesis/Data for Thesis"
Sys.setenv(TEXINPUTS=getwd(),
           BIBINPUTS=getwd(),
           BSTINPUTS=getwd())

x <- c("shiny","flowViz","nls2","plyr","RColorBrewer","abind","MASS","gplots","hexbin",
       "data.table","fastmatch","stringr","hypergeo","rgl","mclust","knitr","dbscan")
lapply(x, require, character.only=T)
# Sweave2knitr('ThesisSecondDraft.Rnw')
@

\begin{document}

\Sexpr{knit_child('Th1_Introduction.Rnw')}

\part{The Experiment}

\Sexpr{knit_child('Th2_Characterisation.Rnw')}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide us a minimal example of your child.Rnw ?

Comment: If I use your minimal example, it won't work because it can't find `opts_chunk`. So I can't reproduce your error

Comment: Ah sorry, only just saw this. My child.Rnw doesn't have any additional code at the beginning. Apart from \ref and \label no longer working, \Sexpr{knit_child... seems to work as if the text and R code that are in the child document are just copy and pasted into the main document. But I will edit it to something more minimal so you can see something that does work for me (even if \ref and \label don't)

Comment: hmmm. I'll think I'll have to retackle this another time. I can't get a minimal example to work for me either. Mostly down to my terrible understanding of how any of this works unfortunately :-(

Comment: I don't really understand it as well, so I mostly stick to my previous templates...sorry if I can't help :/

Comment: Lol, that's exactly my issue. My entire document started as someone else's and then I've just slowly changed it as I go. For whatever reason, I've never managed to get it working as Sweave, so I'm on knitr, and then the moment something just works, I've ran with it... as I said below, my work around is just to delete the chapters when I finally publish it all and I'll just pretend it works until then!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which work on my files.

In the main.Rnw document :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Hello world

\SweaveInput{child_test.Rnw}


\end{document}
```

In the child_test.Rnw file

```
 %!Rnw root = main.Rnw

\SweaveOpts{echo = TRUE, eval = TRUE}

\section{Analysis}
This is the analysis.

<<analysis, result = tex>>=
summary(cars)
@
```

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work for me. My document adds a page at the beginning that just saying "concordance=TRUE", and then where my extra Rnw file should be, I just see "Testing.Rnw". This is what was happening before and is why I switched to \Sexpr{knit_child('Testing.Rnw')} as my way to add Rnw files.

Comment: Strange...but the example I give works in your rstudio? Like if you create a new main.Rnw file ? 
My second idea is that you redefine your working directory, instead of using an Rproject, that might trouble the kniting operation...but I'm not sure

Comment: concordance=TRUE
Hello world
childtest:Rnw

Is what my pdf looks like if I make your test files.

My best idea at the moment is just to put up with the whole thing. Act like it works and put up with the large number of "??" everywhere. When it comes to actually compile it, I'll just have to not use the chapter .Rnw files and I'll just paste everything back into the main file.